# Laravel - One form for different controllers

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multi step registration form which will send data with the same submission to three different resource controllers (to store function), and so models.

The form controller:

```
class Registration extends Controller
{


    public function index() {

        return view('admin.registration');
    }

    public function store(Request $r) {
        Controller1::store($r->step1)
        Controller2::store($r->step2)
        Controller3::store($r->step3)
    }
}
```

How could be a good practice?

Comment: [Here's a laravel wizard on github.](https://github.com/smajti1/laravel-wizard) It's fairly recent and shows one way to do a multi-step controller.

Comment: The problem is how to give the data to different controllers inside the registration controller

Comment: The wizard will be too complicated for him to grasp. @J03Bukowski create database tables for each step. Use the session_id as the reference. Then in the last step, grab all data using session id and store it.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the reply. I have already created 3 tables and 3 controller for each step. The problem is how call a function in each step controller from the registration controller. Obviously every step controllers contain the store functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for calling 3 different controller, rather you should interact with 3 different model. From your code, I am assuming you are submitting your form to `Registration@store`. Here is how the code

Let's assume you have 3 step form

1. Step 1:  get User email, mobile password
2. Step2: User addresses and country
3. Step 3:  User company profile

Once the form is submitted it hit the `store` method. I am also assuming you have 3 table and `3 modal` i.e `User, Profile, CompanyProfile`.

If that's the case my method would be like this

```
public function store(Request $request) {
$data['name'] = $request->get('name');
$data['email'] = $request->get('email');
....................................
....................................
$user  = User:create($data)  //This will create your user modal instance

//Now upload the 2nd steps data

$step2['user_id'] = $user->id;
$step2['locality'] = $request->get('locality');
.....................................
....................................
Profile::create($step2);


$step3['user_id'] = $user->id;
$step3['locality'] = $request->get('locality');
.....................................
....................................
CompanyProfile::create($step3);

return redirect('/home')  //or whereever you want to redirect your user
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I had to send the data to 3 different models. I ended understanding that the only solution is to put everything inside the Registration@store.